# Pandas: Adding new calculated(fractioning) row

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe:

```
  A    B     C   D
0 425  23    765 765
1 543  43552 654 878
2 67   543   675 76
```

I want to create fourth row, which is calculating by summing values from 0 and 1 rows and dividing it by 3 row. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting rows by index, `sum` and last divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df.loc[3, :] = df.loc[:1].sum().div(df.loc[2])
#if need specify 0,1 row index
#df.loc[3, :] = df.loc[[0,1]].sum().div(df.loc[2])
print (df)
            A             B           C           D
0  425.000000     23.000000  765.000000  765.000000
1  543.000000  43552.000000  654.000000  878.000000
2   67.000000    543.000000  675.000000   76.000000
3   14.447761     80.248619    2.102222   21.618421
```

If necessary select by positions and add last row use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.loc[len(df), :] = df.iloc[[0,1]].sum().div(df.iloc[2])
print (df)
            A             B           C           D
0  425.000000     23.000000  765.000000  765.000000
1  543.000000  43552.000000  654.000000  878.000000
2   67.000000    543.000000  675.000000   76.000000
3   14.447761     80.248619    2.102222   21.618421
```